# Which design pattern is suitable illustrated problem below?

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-boot-actuator

I am developing a project in spring boot. There are common **required steps** will be used by all classes in development phase. For example  to make connectivity through jdbc from java program to database the **first step** is load the jdbc driver, **second step** is create connection object and so on.
The problem is design pattern of my project should restrict the new developer of my project to write new classes in such a way that **no requires steps would skip** in such condition which design pattern should i use??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Am not sure about design pattern ,but i suggest to have abstract class /interface with all required methods(or steps as told by you to load the jdbc driver, create connection object and so on) and all new classed should extend or implement above abstract class or interface

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need a design pattern for this at all.  If you are building your project in Spring Boot, just create a [data source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) once and inject it where it is needed.

Sure, Spring might use the Singleton pattern under the covers to make it happen, but that's not relevant to your problem - the framework solves it for you.

Comment: Please add a comment if you downvote an answer.  I'd like to understand what's wrong with using Spring to do something that Spring is good at.